# open setting screen to update location service in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, settings, core-location

I want to open setting app from my app to enable location service if it is off
i have use the following code

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
```

But this is working in iOS 5.0 + it is not wokring below iOS 5.0 
Did any one know hot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This has been disabled in iOS 5. The best you could do is open preferences and tell the user to enable the location services